# Why Does the Existence of Eigenvalue 1 in Odd Dimensions does Extend to Even Dimensions? ($\mathbb{R}$ vector space)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality, isometry

Let $(V,\langle.,.\rangle)$ be a Euclidean vector space defined over $\mathbb{R}$ of odd dimension $n $ and let $f : V \rightarrow V$  an orthogonal mapping with $\operatorname{det}(f)=1 $. Then the map $ f $ has a vector $v \in V \backslash\{0\} $ with $ f(v)=v $.

Now this is obviously true since $ f$ is orthogonal it preserves distances: $||f(v)|| = ||v|| \Rightarrow f(v) = \lambda v \Rightarrow |\lambda| = 1$.

This should be true for even dimensions as well because $||f(v)|| = ||v||$ should hold for every finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$ vector space. Is this the argument here? If there is a more detailed argument, feel free to share!

Comment: The title question is missing a crucial _not_...?

Comment: I don't really see why @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: Lutz Lehmann's answer shows there are rotations of four-space with no real eigenvalues at all, so the existence of a $1$-eigenspace _does not_ extend to even dimensions. :) (This is true in two dimensions, also: Most plane rotations have no real eigenvalue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You showed that all eigenvalues have absolute value one, that is, lie on the unit circle. That does not imply that any of these points is $1+i\,0$.

Remember that in a polynomial with real coefficients, the complex roots come in conjugate pairs.

In $\Bbb R^4$ you can combine a rotation in the first two coordinates with an independent rotation in the second two variables.